# Define date format in Python / Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have two .csv files joined in Python with the Pandas module. One column is date with the format "dd.mm.yyyy".

Now I would like to extract only the month (as 2 digit integer with leading zero) from it for further use.

I have so far accomplished the job but I had to cheat. Python thinks the string that I am getting is the DAY. I don't like half-baked things, so I wanted to ask the community how I can tell Python specifically which part of the date is the month so it can be returned to me?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas

def saison(input):
    if input == "04" or input == "05" or input == "06" or input == "07" or input == "08" or input == "09":
        return "Sommer"
    else:
        return "Winter"

df_1 = pandas.read_csv("a.csv", sep=';', names=["DWD_ID", "Datum"], header=0)
df_2 = pandas.read_csv("b.csv", sep=';', names=[VEG", "DWD_ID"], header=0)
df_joined = pandas.merge(df_1, df_2, on="DWD_ID")
df_joined["Datum"] = pandas.to_datetime(df_joined["Datum"])

df_joined["Saison"] = saison(df_joined["Datum"].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d')))
```

If I use

```
x.strftime('%m')
```

instead it returns me the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could supply the format you want to keep in the arg of [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'], format="%d.%m.%Y").dt.month.astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

Comment: `dayfirst=True` would also work but `format` will be faster and will fail when something goes wrong instead of silently making choices that you might disagree with.

Comment: That did the job! Thanks!

Comment: @Khaled, I see that you haven't accepted answers for any of your prior questions including this one ;-) You should certainly accept them(by clicking on the check mark) if it has solved your problem. This indicates to anyone coming over this page in future that this solution of mine worked to resolve the problem.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I haven't been aware of this feature yet!

Answer (score 1):

First it seems you have swap month and day in datetime, so you need add argument `format='%Y-%d-%m'` to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) ([Python's strftime directives](http://strftime.org/)):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2016-24-02']})  
print (df)
         Date
0  2016-24-02

print (pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%d-%m'))
0   2016-02-24
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

After converting you can use:

[`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
print (df.Date.dt.strftime('%m'))
```

Another solution with extract [`month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html), then convert to `string` and last add zero fill by [`zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
print (df.Date.dt.month.astype(str).str.zfill(2))
```

Sample:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2015-02-24')
rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=10, freq='m')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng})  
print (df)
        Date
0 2015-02-28
1 2015-03-31
2 2015-04-30
3 2015-05-31
4 2015-06-30
5 2015-07-31
6 2015-08-31
7 2015-09-30
8 2015-10-31
9 2015-11-30


print (df.Date.dt.strftime('%m'))
0    02
1    03
2    04
3    05
4    06
5    07
6    08
7    09
8    10
9    11
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

---

```
print (df.Date.dt.month.astype(str).str.zfill(2))
0    02
1    03
2    04
3    05
4    06
5    07
6    08
7    09
8    10
9    11
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Last you can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with condition with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
saison = ["04","05","06","07","08","09"]
df['Saison'] = np.where(df.Date.dt.strftime('%m').isin(saison), 'Sommer','Winter')
print (df)
        Date  Saison
0 2015-02-28  Winter
1 2015-03-31  Winter
2 2015-04-30  Sommer
3 2015-05-31  Sommer
4 2015-06-30  Sommer
5 2015-07-31  Sommer
6 2015-08-31  Sommer
7 2015-09-30  Sommer
8 2015-10-31  Winter
9 2015-11-30  Winter
```